# listview must show all the list of items

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/asda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="318dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/asda"
    android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_btn_scannewitem"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Scan New Item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_btn_saveNewItem"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="Save Your Item"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_btn_changeprofile"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="Change Profile" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

I have used this code but i dint get the design 
 what i am expecting instead i am getting the page like this.
[with the listview having olny limited list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJfrR.png)

but  i am expecting the design like this.!
[the second image is what i am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bBSk.png)

Comment: just limit your data you sent to `Adapter`

Comment: You have hard coded the height of list view try to use `wrap_content` instead of `android:layout_height="318dp"`

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to wrap your `ListView` into a `LinearLayout`, and you can set your `ListView` height to `match_parent` or `fill_parent`.

Also, remove the `android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"` attribute from the `TableLayout` below the list.